# unlisting you tube video, uploaded from ios application

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am uploading videos to you tube from my iOS application using GData. But I want to change the access control property of the videos to "unlisted". So that, only people using my application can view the video.

I tried to use the function:

```
+ (GDataYouTubeAccessControl *)accessControlWithAction:(NSString *)action
                                        permission:(NSString *)permission
```

in "GDataYouTubeAccessControl.h" for this, but it does not have "unlist" in the constants.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: i solved it my self, by using: addAccessControl method

Comment: You should post the above comment as an answer and then accept it. :)

Comment: I am not able to answer my own question as I my reputation is not over 100.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to upload a video as 'Unlisted'.

Since I wasn't using an updated version of the GData APIs, first I had to make the changes listed here :

[ http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/detail?r=669 ]

Then I used the following code to set the video as 'Unlisted', while uploading it to Youtube :

```
GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                      data:data
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                      slug:filename];

[entry addAccessControl:[GDataYouTubeAccessControl
                        accessControlWithAction:@"list" permission:@"denied"]];
```

Make sure the video is **NOT** set as 'Private' for this to work :

```
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:NO];
```

Got some major help from :

[ http://groups.google.com/group/gdata-objectivec-client/browse_thread/thread/da69a5ecbb6dfa42?fwc=1 ]